# WPF Datagrid in ScrollViewer with Dockpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer, dockpanel

I want to make my UI more responsable and right now I have this problem:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding StatusColor}"></Ellipse>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusText}" ToolTip="{Binding StatusToolTip}"></TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusLastAction}"></TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            //
            // Fields to edid data from MySelectedItem
            //
        </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <DataGrid MinHeight="150" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works like a charm until the point when the `DataGrid` gets to many items. The grid doesn't create a own scrollviewer it just uses the full height from the "Main"-`ScrollViewer`. (see image below - bottom-right)

---

Look here for [wanted UI design (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SyNI.png)

**black** > `Window`

**green** > `Scrollviewer`

**red** > `DataGrid`

**orange** > `fields to edit data`

---

**top left image (good):**

- there is enough space in the window to show everything
- the `DataGrid` (red) fills the available space and has a own scoll viewer if there are to many items to show

**top right image (good):**

- there isn't enough space to show all
- the 'DataGrid' uses the min-height and the `ScrollViewer` (green) gets visible to show the rest (orange)

**bottom left image (bad):**

- there is not enough space to show all
- the `DataGrid` doen't use the min-height

**bottom right image (bad):**

- there is enough space to show everything
- the `DataGrid` uses all needed space to show all `Item`

---

Is there a way to design the UI as shown in the top images?

Comment: looks like `MaxHeight` set on DataGrid should help

Comment: When I set `MaxHeight` it won't be responsive at some point. So this isn't a real opportunity.. but thanks for the idea!

Comment: Use  scrollview inside your data grid and set its `MaxHeight`  `<DataGrid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >`

Comment: @CelsoLívero when I set MaxHeight it won't be responsive.. so thats not what I want..

Comment: @bene_rawr  it is a unique way to fit into your scenario, put the `MaxHeight` of the DataGrid` to be, for example, 90% of your visible area of the screen, see, just, let's MaxHeight, that is, it may still be smaller, but not larger, `MaxHeight = {Binding MaxHeightProperty}`, and in your ViewModel you can calculate the MaxHeight

Answer (score 1):

I usually do not create screens so that they have an external scroll, that makes everything else complicated.
According to what you illustrated in the image, your `DataGrid` should have no height greater than the height of the screen.

So what you need to do is set a size for your grid, example: 60%, 70%, 80% of the height of your screen and the rest your other information

In the solution below I leave the `DataGrid` always with 80% of the height on the screen

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        .....
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Name="MainWindowName"
        >

<DataGrid Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainWindowName, Converter={StaticResource PercentConverter}}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
          />
```

**Converter Class**

```
public class PercentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return 0;
        var valor = (int)(int.Parse(value.ToString()) * 0.8); //80% of my Window Height
        return valor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valor = (int)(int.Parse(value.ToString()) / 0.8);
        return valor;
    }
}
```

I tested with a large number of data generated in a simple loop

**ViewModel** (My test)

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
    for (var i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
        MyItems.Add(new MyData { Id = i, Name = GenerateNames() });

}

private string GenerateNames()
{
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var n = _random.Next(5, 15);
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, n).Select(s => s[_random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

resulting in the image below, and whatever the size of the window the DataGrid will be 80% of the height of it

[image: Imagem 01]

Edit:
if you do not need the external scroll, ie if it is possible to keep everything visible at the same time on the screen the best way is to leave everything with relative position, this way:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="6*"/> // 6* 
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- 6 *, 3 *, *, Auto, <fixed value> are possible values at row height, 6 and 3 means how much of the ratio I'm adding to them -->

<Grid Grid.Row="0" >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Margin="10,10,10,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
              />
</Grid>

<Grid  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="This is an example"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="This is an example"/>
</Grid>

<StatusBar Grid.Row="2"  
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Margin="0,0,0,0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem>
        <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding StatusColor}"></Ellipse>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusText}" ToolTip="{Binding StatusToolTip}"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusLastAction}"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: one more thing, you can change a lot of what you want in your converter, `value` is the Window's ActualHeight, so you can use your Convert to change the size of the Grid according to the size of the window, that is, it can have a proportion larger or smaller according to the size of your window